# multiple kafka schema registry against same cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to mount two instances of kafka schema registry against the same kafka and zookeeper cluster. But the shemas are getting mixed. When running the two registries, if I register a schema using the api "kafka-schema-registry" it appears to be created at "schema-registry-ui-other" and not showing at "kafka-schema-registry-ui" as expected.
My configuration is:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./full-stack/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./full-stack/zoo1/datalog:/datalog


  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./full-stack/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  kafka-schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka-schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: kafka-schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_GROUP_ID: "schema-registry"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
  kafka-schema-registry-other:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka-schema-registry-other
    ports:
      - "8092:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: kafka-schema-registry-other
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_ZK_NAMESPACE: schema_registry_other
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC: "_schemas_other"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_GROUP_ID: "schema-registry-other"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1

  schema-registry-ui:
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui:0.9.4
    hostname: kafka-schema-registry-ui
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    environment:
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL: http://kafka-schema-registry:8081/
      PROXY: "true"
    depends_on:
      - kafka-schema-registry

  schema-registry-ui-other:
    image: landoop/schema-registry-ui:0.9.4
    hostname: kafka-schema-registry-ui-other
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
    environment:
      SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL: http://kafka-schema-registry-other:8081/
      PROXY: "true"
    depends_on:
      - kafka-schema-registry-other

  kafka-rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka-rest-proxy
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      # KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082/
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://kafka-schema-registry:8081/
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
      - kafka-schema-registry

  kafka-topics-ui:
    image: landoop/kafka-topics-ui:0.9.4
    hostname: kafka-topics-ui
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL: "http://kafka-rest-proxy:8082/"
      PROXY: "true"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
      - kafka-schema-registry
      - kafka-rest-proxy
  zoonavigator-web:
    image: elkozmon/zoonavigator-web:0.5.1
    ports:
     - "8004:8000"
    environment:
      API_HOST: "zoonavigator-api"
      API_PORT: 9000
    links:
     - zoonavigator-api
    depends_on:
     - zoonavigator-api

  zoonavigator-api:
    image: elkozmon/zoonavigator-api:0.5.1
    environment:
      SERVER_HTTP_PORT: 9000
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
```

it's not possible to have two separated schemas registry ?

Comment: It should be *possible*, although, I'm not sure I understand why you would need to.... If you really wanted to see which registry is used, you should use console consumer on the two schemas topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the Group ID incorrectly for the Schema Registry servers, which means they are in the same consumer group, which means they consider themselves part of the same cluster.  The second Schema Registry server becomes the primary, and so performs all of the writes.

You can fix this by setting the environment variable `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_GROUP_ID` for both of the Schema Registry servers.  They will then be considered to be two different clusters, and this will work as you expect it to.