# two completely different schema-registry for same broker cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am running two schema registry for same kafka broker cluster with different `kafkastore.topic` on different machine.

```
kafkastore.topic=_DEV_schemas
kafkastore.topic=_QA_schemas
```

The instance comes without any issues and runs fine. But the problem start when i tries to create a new schema on DEV its goes to QA. so,

Is it not possible to run two different schema-registry for same broker cluster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You need to set both the topic and the listener address to different values

Comment: Sorry, I know this is possible but its not working, i have different listener address and topic name but that is not working.

Comment: Please upload both of your full configuration files. Also make sure that your clients are using the different URLs for each registry

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571410/5650306

> setting environment variable **schema.registry.group.id** for **both** of the Schema Registry servers.
> https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html#schema-registry-group-id